Use other units than point for arraycolsep
The following code throws an error stating that \arraycolsep needs the length unit specified in points. Is it possible to use other units, e.g., mu?
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{3mu}
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}ccc@{}}
    x_{-1}, & x_0, & x_1 \\
    x_0, & x_1, & x_2
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}



The error message does not say that the it needs points, the message is
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   m
l.5   \setlength{\arraycolsep}{3mu}


So it tells you that mu is not a valid unit (so it will use pt)  you can use any tex unit, so in, cm, sp etc.
mu is not a unit that can be used with any dimen or glue setting it is a math unit  which is a special construct only allowed with mu-specific registers and for example \muskip primitive not \hskip or \vskip.
All TeX dimen units are just used as fixed conversion multipliers at the point they are used. The actual length is always an integer multiple of sp.
mu are different, 3mu does not denote a fixed length: you can store it in a \muskip register and save it as 3mu but the actual length will be determined when this length is used being multipled at that time by 1em/18 of the font set as \textfont2 (or \script(script)font2) in the current math list.

Thank you very much for the explanation! I should probably read the error messages more carefully. So, if I understand it correctly, the only way to get mu spacing in an array is to set arraycolsep to 0 and insert mkerns or muskips in the cells.

@EuklidAlexandria well unless you are going to suddenly place the table in a superscript you can just use normal units and just use em units divided by 18

Ok, that makes sense, thank you!
